# Access 2013: copy data to Excel and print (VBA)

Tags: excel, ms-access, copy, vba, field

I'd like a button that, when clicked, copies data from "field1" and "field2" into an Excel spreadsheet to "field 3" and "field 4" and prints the outcome.

Basically, once someone places an order and I click the "Paid" button, it pushes the info into a template and prints.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should get you started. The Excel template `OrderSheet.xltx` has two single-cell Named Ranges: `field3` and `field4`. The rest should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
Private Sub cmdPlaceOrder_Click()
Dim objExcel As Object  '' Excel.Application
Dim objSheet As Object  '' Excel.Worksheet
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Add "C:\Users\Public\OrderSheet.xltx"
objExcel.Range("field3").Value = Me.txtField1.Value
objExcel.Range("field4").Value = Me.txtField2.Value
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveSheet
objSheet.PrintOut
Set objSheet = Nothing
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False  '' save changes = No
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, i tried the code and made some adjustments but i cannot compile. what am i doing wrong?

Private Sub PayStatus_Click()
Read PayStatus
If PayStatus = "paid" Then
    Dim objExcel As Object  '' Excel.Application
    Dim objSheet As Object  '' Excel.Worksheet
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Workbooks.Add "C:\Users\Weusi\Desktop\Receipts.xltx"
    objExcel.Range("BookingNumber").Value = Me.BookingNumber.Value
    objExcel.Range("DateBooked").Value = Me.DateBooked.Value
    Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveSheet
    objSheet.PrintOut
    objSheet = Nothing

Comment: [objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False  '' save changes = No
   objExcel.Quit
    objExcel = Nothing
End If

Comment: @user2325065 What is the compile error message and what line is highlighted?